# Adding a row in DataTable jquery, how it works?

Tags: jquery, datatables

When using jQuery DataTables I have my table in `self.table` variable and I'm trying: `self.table.fnAddData();` and `self.table.row.add();` nothing...

What could be wrong?

Comment: `self.table.row.add().Draw();` - still nothing

Comment: could you elaborate your issue. also if possible can you create a jsfiddle, http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: I don't think I can create a jsfiddle, cuz I'm getting my data, lines, columns from the DB!

Comment: So you want to add a new entry on your DB and show the new row with that entry at DataTable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **SOLUTION**

**For DataTables 1.10 and above**

- If table is initialized with `DataTable()`:

  ```
  self.table = $('#example').DataTable();
  self.table.row.add([/* data goes here */]).draw();
  ```
- If table is initialized with `dataTable()`:

  ```
  self.table = $('#example').dataTable();
  self.table.api().row.add([/* data goes here */]).draw();
  ```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, could you please tell me,
how about, If I have no Idea how many columns will have my table cuz AddRow will be applied to all my tables, and I want no data on it when I add a row?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: @AlexMcManns, to clear the table you can use [`self.table.clear()`](http://datatables.net/reference/api/clear%28%29) before adding the rows. For dynamic table you would need to recreate the table and re-initialize DataTables plug-in before you can add the data with different number of columns.

Comment: ok, but is there any way to add a blank row? without a `add([/* data */])`

Comment: @AlexMcManns, why do you want to add a blank row? It makes no sense. To change the message in the empty table, use [`language.emptyTable`](http://datatables.net/reference/option/language.emptyTable) option instead.

Comment: We have a website, where we can load all our tables from DB, with different columns and rows, that can be edited, deleted etc. Now I want to add a blank row, with the same number and type of colums (we have different columns ex: string, int, double etc) where we can type data desired and save it back to DB. Voila!

Comment: @AlexMcManns, You can try enumerate your columns with [`columns.every()`](http://datatables.net/reference/api/columns%28%29.every%28%29) and prepare the data for the new row accordingly.

Comment: So that'd be like 
`self.table = $('#example').dataTable();
self.table.columns.every();` and where put `api().row.add().draw()` ?
Thank you!